# why using java bean and not standard scriptlets

Tags: jsp, javabeans, scriptlet

I'm studying Java EE and reading a chapter that talks about Javabeans, and `jsp:setproperty`.

The example is:

```
<jsp:useBean id="user1" class="User" />
<jsp:setProperty id="user1" property="name" value="Johnnie" />
```

Why should I even bother doing this? and not using the following code in my jsp:

```
<%
User user1 = new User();
user1.setName('johnnie');
%>
```